# How do I stop my monitor screen from jittering when playing games?

Tags: display, hdmi, connection, gaming, usb-hub

I have a Surface Book 2 15 and am connecting it to a Dell S2721QS 4K monitor using a USB hub to connect be HDMI. The screen is mostly fine when just browsing the web, but once I launch a game and play it on the monitor screen, the screen starts flickering. I have reinstalled/updated my drivers, updated my computer, lowered the resolution, upped the refresh rate, and restarted my computer to no avail. The hub I am using is an Anker 5-in-1. I have also tried a Baseus one and while that one doesn't have any jitter problems, it disconnects frequently (again, pretty much only when I play games). Anyone know what the issue is? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing the hub/adapter isn't capable of sending data quickly enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that all of these types of things (basically port replicators) have technically their own graphics card built into them. So whilst they are usually fine for office work and videos they struggle doing more complex stuff. Added to the fact they are working on a reduced bandwidth by going via USB.

I was surprised to see that your device doesn't appear to have any sort of video output port (HDMI, display port etc). So I think the only solution you are like to have is play it on the devices screen, not an external monitor. Which I am guessing is OK.